# Deepin 15.11 Fresh Install Prevents Eset Nod32 from Activating and Pinging Its Servers

Tags: networking, debian, installation, eset, nod32

I did a fresh install of Deepin 15.11 Desktop on a 64-bit AMD system that is dual-booted with Windows 10. I wanted to install ESET Nod32 Antivirus on Deepin and I can't get past the setup for a free trial. I have a key but it doesn't get through the setup enough to send me an email with a username and password. So I was trying the free trial option.

The GUI just comes up and shows Activation Failed and below that it says something like virus definition could not be updated. I tried to ping u20.eset.com and it freezes halfway through. Is there something in a fresh Deepin install that is blocking it? Is there any dependencies that need installed? I'm not sure where to go from here.

P.S. I tried to ping u20.eset.com on my Ubuntu 18.04 system that I've been using for a long time and it does the same thing. Strange.

On Deepin:

```
$ ping u20.eset.com
PING u20.eset.com (91.228.164.22) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Using traceroute:

```
$ traceroute  u20.eset.com
traceroute to u20.eset.com (91.228.164.22), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.128.1 (192.168.128.1)  1.002 ms  1.195 ms  1.277 ms
 2  68.29.129.3 (68.29.129.3)  39.504 ms  39.719 ms  39.698 ms
 3  * * *
 4  66.1.34.5 (66.1.34.5)  51.303 ms 66.1.34.13 (66.1.34.13)  51.518 ms  51.496 ms
 5  144.228.22.25 (144.228.22.25)  55.213 ms 144.228.22.29 (144.228.22.29)  55.430 ms  55.412 ms
 6  144.232.12.251 (144.232.12.251)  58.366 ms  51.622 ms  47.566 ms
 7  144.232.14.5 (144.232.14.5)  54.531 ms  54.734 ms  63.464 ms
 8  144.232.14.10 (144.232.14.10)  66.793 ms  66.518 ms  77.357 ms
 9  62.156.128.109 (62.156.128.109)  59.330 ms  63.481 ms  59.451 ms
10  217.239.55.238 (217.239.55.238)  164.412 ms  164.368 ms  151.892 ms
11  217.239.55.238 (217.239.55.238)  155.259 ms  148.267 ms  147.812 ms
12  80.150.170.82 (80.150.170.82)  155.125 ms  154.803 ms  151.134 ms
13  dupdevs-static-222.213-81-253.telecom.sk (213.81.253.222)  157.420 ms st-static-bckb-20.213-81-252.telecom.sk (213.81.252.20)  151.131 ms dupdevs-static-222.213-81-253.telecom.sk (213.81.253.222)  160.545 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Using nslookup

```
$ nslookup  u20.eset.com
Server:     192.168.128.1
Address:    192.168.128.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   u20.eset.com
Address: 91.228.164.22
```

Comment: Try to use traceroute, nslookup like tools to check if that URL is reachable from your PC.

Comment: Updated my question with the results.